# How to make amd-dependency dynamic in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, amd

I would like to load a Javascript language bundle file dynamically in Typescript based on the current language.

Currently, the only way to make sure my file is loaded before my module is to use a comment like this:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="<path_to_bundle>"/>
```

However, this is static, and I cannot load only the active language bundle.

I could possibly convert my JS resource bundles into Typescript classes with static object properties, but that seems like a lot of work.

Is there any way to load a JS module dynamically before my TS class executes?
This seems like a show-stopper for me to use TypeScript.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: This seems more like a bundling concern than a Typescript concern. How is your loader specification currently working?

Comment: Actually, I figured I can use a require plugin ojL10n in Oracle JET, which does exactly what I want, it loads the right resource bundle based on the selected language.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to load a JS module dynamically before my TS class executes

Use the *dynamic* requirejs API i.e.

```
require('path_to_bundle',()=>{
  // Bundle is loaded
});
```

## PS

install the require js types `npm install @types/requirejs --save-dev` More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/@types.html

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, although I wanted to avoid using require call in typescript.
Actually, I figured I can use a require plugin ojL10n in Oracle JET, which does exactly what I want, it loads the right resource bundle based on the selected language.